Difference between Data Object Index and Cryptomatte Object?
Blender Cycles What is difference between Data: Object Index, Material Index and Cryptomatte: Object, Material, Asset?

Have you referenced the Blender documentation?

Object/Material Indexes were Blender's own (older) implementation of masking. They are limited mainly because the mask is binary, each pixel can only fully belong to one object or material. This results in issues when partial occlusion is involved.
Cryptomatte is an industry standard implementation where a single pixel can have contributions from multiple objects or materials. This makes the mask a lot more flexible when your render contains effect like motion blur, transparency, or depth of field.
Here is an example scene containing a few moving objects and a semi-transparent volume in the foreground:

Here is the Object ID mask (It will always be noisy due to motionblur, even though the image is rendered at 1000 samples:

This is the Cryptomatte mask:

As you can see, cryptomatte has a lot more fidelity.
Cryptomatte also has the benefit that you don't have to manually set the IDs ahead of time, everything is referenced using the name of the asset in the scene. So we can query for 'Cone' object instead of object with ID=3.
